# How to fix RuntimeError: Bool type is not supported by dlpack

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, dgl

I have been using the following code to get the default Cora dataset provided by DGL, but the following error suddenly occurred today.

The code was runned in CoLab (python 3.7 and Pytorch backend). I believed this is a error from the DGL update (since it had worked all the time before). However, I just wonder if there is anything we can do on our end to fix this?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please provide your code in text!

Answer (score 5):

It seems that an error is from torch update to 1.10.0. Reinstalling torch to 1.9.1 works for me. You can reinstall torch in colab as follows:

```
!pip install dgl==0.6.1
!pip install torch==1.9.1
import dgl
cora = dgl.data.CoraGraphDataset()
```

Comment: installing the last version of dgl is also works well
```!pip install dgl -f https://data.dgl.ai/wheels/repo.html```

Comment: I tried version 0.6.1  and get the same error. Which version works for you?

Answer (score -1):

installing the last GPU accelerated(cuda 11.1) dgl with  `pip install dgl-cu111 -f https://data.dgl.ai/wheels/repo.html`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).